# What have I done incorrectly in integration by parts for $f(x) = (2x+4) \cos(2x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

We have $f(x) = (2x+4) \cos(2x)$

My method was integration by parts, and this is my calculation:

$$ \displaystyle \int \cos(2x) \cdot (2x+4) dx = \sin(2x)\cdot (2x-4) - \displaystyle\int \sin(2x) \cdot 2 dx$$

So our answer is:

$$ \displaystyle \int \displaystyle \cos(2x) \cdot (2x+4) dx = \sin(2x) \cdot (2x-4) + \cos(2x) +c$$

Apparently, this is incorrect; but I have no idea why. Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: The primitive of $\cos (2x)$ is $\frac12 \sin(2x)$. And you changed $(2x + 4)$ to $(2x - 4)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Answer it in the question so I can give you the best answer. I hate to ask these types of questions, but my mind is just weird; once I get a solution I can't seem to figure out what's wrong, if the solution is wrong.

Comment: @DanielFischer You may consider turning your comment into an answer, so that this question is more likely to be removed from the "UNANSWERED" tab.

Comment: I'd recommend against only using integration by parts here, if allowed. $(2x+4)\cos{(2x)}=2x\cos{(2x)}+4\cos{(2x)}$. Use standard integration formula for the second term, parts for the first. Then collect like terms. Since the second part can be done mentally and the simplified first part is easier to integrate, mistakes are less likely to happen and there's a speed boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes. One is probably a typo, you changed the $(2x + 4)$ factor of the integrand to $(2x - 4)$.

The other is that you didn't account for the factor $2$ in applying the inverse of the chain rule, the primitive of $\cos (2x)$ is $\frac12\sin(2x)$, and then the same once more, the primitive of $\sin(2x)$ is $-\frac12\cos(2x)$, so overall we obtain

$$\int \cos (2x)\cdot(2x+4)\,dx = \frac12\sin (2x)\cdot(2x+4) - \int \sin (2x)\,dx = (x+2)\sin (2x) + \frac12\cos (2x) + c.$$